# Entity framework and MVC3 include method

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

LINQ "include" missing. after reading this post:
http://romiller.com/2010/07/14/ef-ctp4-tips-tricks-include-with-lambda/

i would like to use include. 
this is my class:

```
public class Service
{

#region Properties

/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets CatalogRootNodeId.
/// </summary>
public virtual int CatalogRootNodeId { get; set; }


/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets ServiceDomain.
/// </summary>
public virtual ICollection<ServiceDomain> ServiceDomain { get; set; }

#endregion
}
```

I would like to "Include" all ServiceDomains but "Include" option is not there
??
I'm working with MVC3 and EF.
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using CTP5 or CTP4?
If you do, you can use the extension method from System.Data.Entity.DbExtensions.Include.

```
public static IQueryable<T> Include<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, object>> path)


var db = new MyDbContext();
var services = db.Services.Where(s => s.CatalogRootNodeId == 1).Include(s => s.ServiceDomain);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `Include()` on the `ObjectSet<Service>` from the `DataContext`.